# Flutter cannot get resource X86-64-debug

Tags: flutter

I am just new to Flutter and I am trying to create the web according to my colleague's code but I engage the error below:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not download x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32.jar'.
  >   Connect to storage.googleapis.com:443 [storage.googleapis.com/172.217.160.80] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

flutter version
Flutter 1.17.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f7a6a7906b (4 days ago) • 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
Engine • revision 6bc433c6b6
Tools • Dart 2.8.2

enviroment variables
FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL is https://storage.flutter-io.cn,
PUB_HOSTED_URL is https://pub.flutter-io.cn

May I have your help for the issue, it looks like a connection problem but I can get the X86_Debug download in the brower while I can't determine where to place the file. Maybe the directory where the file placed could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a VPN worked for me. I am using protonVPN.